# Can a relevant operator's OPE with itself only include the identity and irrelevant operators?

Tags: operators, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, correlation-functions

I am interested in correlation functions in critical spin chains, and I'm trying to understand the consequences of conformal field theory for these correlation functions. I should warn that I do not have a strong CFT background. This is a question related to that goal.

I've heard of the OPE, which allows one to rewrite products of fields in terms of sums of fields:
$\phi_i(x) \phi_j(y) = \sum_k C_{ij}^k(x-y) \phi_k(\frac{x+y}{2})$. I want to understand what total scaling dimensions $\Delta$ can appear in the product.

In particular, suppose I had a relevant operator $\phi$ and I consider the OPE of $\phi(x) \phi(y)$. Such an OPE will contain the identity operator with scaling dimension zero, but can all the remaining operators in the OPE have large, irrelevant scaling dimensions?

---

I am most interested in the case of $d=2$ unitary minimal models like the Ising model and whether this might or might not be possible for some given minimal model of central charge $c$.